# Is there a reason to NOT use double quotes in a CSV file?

Tags: regex, vb.net, csv

I am creating a CSV file to upload to a website that throws a fit if there's so much as an unescaped full stop.

In trying to find out which fields needed escaping I had <strike>a headache</strike> fun learning a bit of regex, but is this pointless?  Is there any reason not to just enclose every field in double quotes and be done with it?

It seems overkill, but then maybe searching each string is more overkill, heh.

Here's my function:

```
Private Sub WriteToCSVFile(ByVal s As String(,), ByVal sFileName As String)
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    For i As Integer = 0 To s.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j As Integer = 0 To s.GetUpperBound(1)
            If Regex.Match(s(i, j), "^[\w ]*$").Success Then
                sb.Append(s(i, j) & IIf(j = s.GetUpperBound(1), "", ","))
            Else
                sb.Append("""" & s(i, j) & IIf(j = s.GetUpperBound(1), """", ""","))
            End If
        Next
        sb.AppendLine()
    Next

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\" & sFileName, sb.ToString)

End Sub
```

Comment: You still need to escape double quotes

Comment: There is no reason that any/all `Text` fields shouldn't be quoted.  Some programs (older version of Excel) will treat quoted fields as text regardless of their content (eg. numbers) so that may or may not be an issue for you.

Answer (score 3):

A downside (since you asked if there are any) is that adding quotes unconditionally possibly increases the size of the CSV file, the time taken to read the file, and the memory footprint when the file is being processed.  Unless memory and storage are particularly constrained, however, the practical impact is very likely negligible.

There is no authoritative standard for the CSV format, although [RFC4180](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) attempts to define one.  RFC4180 allows the double quotes in all cases, with the caveat that some systems may not support this convention:

> Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
>          some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
>          at all).

If the consumer of the CSV file is compliant with this part of the RFC, then enclosing all fields in double quotes is fine.

Answer (score 3):

The major downside I have encountered with using double quotes as delimiters and commas as separators is that the source data sometimes contains them, which often causes errors when processing the data (unless you write code to handle it).  I prefer not to use any delimiter at all and use a pipe instead of a comma to separate the values. While is conceivable that your source data may contain a pipe, it is not nearly as likely as the more common characters used to delimit and separate data in CSV files.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using double quotes around strings and not around numbers. You'll need to write some code that escapes double quotes *inside* your strings as well.

For example:

```
1,"Charles ""Pretty Boy"" Floyd","1 Short St, Smallville"
2,"Charlie ""Lucky"" Luciano","1 Short St, Smallville"
```

The additional overhead is trivial when you take into account that it actually works.

Answer (score -1):

I found it easier to simply replace all quotes and commas in my source data with known strings like `~~~DoubleQuote~~~`, `~~~SingleQuote~~~`, and `~~~Comma~~~`. Once these were replaced in the source it was a simple matter of storing the values in quote-comma format. Which is still readable.

If you don't care about the human re-ability or writing queries against your stored values, then you could simply use 64-bit encoder to convert your random user provided text into simple alphanumeric strings. The added benefit is that once encoded it's really difficult for a user to create something which can break your routine.